# replace all symlinks with original

Tags: bash, symlink

I have the following directory structure

```
/symdir
  sym1 -> ../dir1
  sym2 -> ../dir2
  hello.txt
```

And then

```
/dir1
  some
  files
  here
/dir2
  more
  files
```

I would like to replace the symlinks in symdir (sym1, sym2) with the originals.  I.e.

```
some_awesome_bash_func symdir symdir_output
```

Would create

```
/symdir_output
  /dir1
    some
    files
    here
  /dir2
    more
    files
  hello.txt
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: script it with `cp`, `mkdir` and `readlink`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably not the best way, but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for link in $(find /symdir -type l)
do
  loc="$(dirname "$link")"
  dir="$(readlink "$link")"
  mv "$dir" "$loc"
  rm "$link"
done
```

Comment: `readlink "$link"` gives the next link... `readlink -e "$link"` gives the final target of a chain of links.

Comment: Be aware that you must not have any file name with spaces; otherwise the `mv` command breakes

Comment: This doesn't "work" - it will simply move the linked files to the directory in which the link was found. What if the linked files are named differently to their links?

Answer (score 72):

My very personal trick for files (not directories):

```
sed -i '' **/*
```

Note that I'm using `**` which uses the bash globstar option, you may have to enable it beforehand:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

### How it works

I trick `sed` to do the job, by using an implementation detail of the `sed` inplace mode.

`sed` is a tool to edit streams of text. The `-i` option of `sed` means `inplace`, the empty string `''` is the instruction set: so there's no instruction, `sed` will do nothing. `**/*` is a bash `globstar` pattern meaning "all files and all folders, at all depth, from here".

The algorithm `sed` uses to edit a file inplace is:

- Create a temporary file as the output file,
- for each line in the input file:

  - apply the transformation, write to the output file.
- Move the output file over the input file.

As I'm asking no transformations (the empty string), the algorithm can be simplified as:

- Create a temporary file,
- copy the content of the original file to the temporary file
- move the temporary file over the original file.

The temporary file is a real file, `sed` completly ignores that the input file was a symlink, it just reads it. So at the last step, when `sed` moves the temporary file over the real file, it "overwrite" the symlink with a real file, that's what we wanted.

This also explains why it won't work to transform a "symlink to a directory" to a real directory: `sed` works on file contents.

Comment: What does it do ? How could `sed` possibly copy files ?

Comment: Very interesting. I'm a bit surprised this works. (cc @LeVieuxGildas - it *does* work)

Comment: @nikana-reklawyks sed -i FILE work like 'TMP=$(mktemp); cat $FILE | sed ... > $TMP; mv $TMP $FILE;' so without the --follow-symlinks option it will effectively do the trick :)

Comment: @ZacharyVance If you have a better / cleaner / whatever solution, feel free to post it ;-)

Comment: `sed -i '' **/*` by itself did not work but specifying the files more explicitly it worked: `sed -i '' *.txt`

Comment: @GeorgePligor You're probably missing the globstar option, I specify this in my answer.

Comment: ELI5:

`**/*` expands all files in directory to the command

`sed -i '' `changes nothing in the content of the file

This takes advantage of the fact sed uses temp files and replace the origin, looks like it works well for directories too.
source: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9ktb2o/using_sed_to_replace_symlinks_with_a_copy_of_the/

Comment: but sadly it has a problem with directories that are symbolic links... sed: couldn't edit <filename>: not a regular file

Comment: @Manticore you're right, never had the issue but worth mentionning.

Comment: This _is_ a cool hack, but such an answer should really, _really_ contain an explanation for how/why/when it works.

Comment: @leftaroundabout good idea, is it better? Anything I can enhance?

Comment: Note that you need GNU `sed` for this to work. This does not work with FreeBSD `sed` such as the one shipped with macOS.

Answer (score 34):

You can do this easily with rsync:

```
rsync symdir/ symdir_output/ -a --copy-links -v
```

(-a means preserve basically every detail about the files, --copy-links overrides -a to turn symlinks into the real files/directories, and -v is for verbose)

Edit:

Sorry, my solution doesn't do exactly what you asked for. It will preserve the symlink's names instead of using the destination names. symdir_output would have sym1 and sym2 instead of dir1 and dir2 (though sym1 and sym2 would be a real copy of dir1 and dir2). Hope it still works for you.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this was the exact solution I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

a related answer, this solution keeps the file at it's original place and creates a copy in place of the symlink

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type l)
do
    cp --remove-destination $(readlink -e $f) $f
done
```

Comment: This solution (replacing 'cp' with 'mv' and removing '--remove-destination') was the only one that worked exactly as I expected. It replaces the symlinks with the original files and deletes the old location.

Comment: You'll want to double-quote those parameter expansions; also use `readlink -f` to if the directory is anything other than `./`:  `for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type l)
do
    cp --remove-destination "$(readlink -f "$f")" "$f"
done`.  And be aware that splitting of the loop arguments is suspect...

Comment: I'd recommend using `readlink -e` rather than plain `readlink`.  Plain `readlink` will return the path the symlink points to, even if there's no file there. Better to fail on the `readlink` step than the `cp` step.

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr: much more general, much more reliable answer:

```
find -type l -exec sh -c 'PREV=$(realpath -- "$1") && rm -- "$1" && cp -ar -- "$PREV" "$1"' resolver {} \;
```

The "rsync-to-other-destination" approach is strictly superior, and usually leads to better design.

The answer by @PinkFloyd doesn't quite work with unusual filenames, "buried" symlinks, or symlinked directories.  I came here because I wanted to resolve directory-symlinks, so I expect others to find this question for this reason, too.  Also, my version of `cp` (GNU coreutils 8.25) doesn't properly handle `--remove-destination`for @PinkFloyd's answer to work with directories.  So this answer uses manual `rm`.

Also note:

- absence of `-rf`.  That's because a symlink is not a directory, and should not need `-r`.  And unless you have symlinks with restricted permissions (why would you ever want that?!), you don't need `-f` either.
- `realpath` is perfectly fine in this context, because it allows us to find out the actual location in the current system, in the current context, and nothing else matters.  This path won't be written to disk, so this is not an error.
- the `resolver` string is for `sh`.  See `man sh`.
- the double-dashes everywhere are necessary, in case some symlink is called `--version` or similar.
- due to the preorder-guarantee of `find` ("parent directory is listed at somewhere before its content"), this would first replace the parent directory, and then any symlinks within the symlinked directory.  So it would work perfectly fine with "stacked" symlinks.

Comment: @Madeo I guess you're using some weird implementation of "find" that doesn't implement "-type"; perhaps you're using MacOS? Use one of the plenty other answers, for example the rsync one as I recommend. Or install GNU find, because you will run into similar problems again. "macos homebrew gnu find" seems to be a good search string.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Julien's suggestion. This command recursively replaces all symbolic links in the current directory with it's target.

```
find . -type l -exec sed -i '' {} \;
```

- `find .`: Search in the current directory, recursively
- `-type l`: Finds symlinks only
- `-exec sed -i '' {} \;`: Run `sed -i '' PATH` for each symlink. Please see Julien's answer for an excellent explanation of why we use `sed` here.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
ls -la | awk '/-\>/{system("rm "$10); system("cp "$12" .")}'
```

How it works:

`ls -la` outputs something like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  groupname   44 10 Oct 12:17 Queue.swift -> ../../../Platform/DataStructures/Queue.swift
```

Column 10 is `Queue.swift` which is the name of the local file.
Column 12 is `../../../Platform/DataStructures/Queue.swift` which is the name of the link target

The first part of the `awk` command is `'/-\>/'` which means "match lines which contain `->` using a regex

The next part of the awk command is two calls to `system`

First `system("rm "$10)` which expands to `system("rm Queue.swift")`.
This will cause the original file (the symlink) to get deleted

Second is `system("cp "$12" .")` which expands to `system("cp ../../../Platform/DataStructures/Queue.swift .")`

Putting it all together, what happens is for each file (which is a symlink), first we delete the symlink, then we copy the target file in it's place.

---

Although it's not part of the original question, I was using this in conjunction with git. If you happen to be doing that too, you can run `git status .` afterwards and you should see a bunch of type changes (and nothing else), like this:

```
typechange: Queue.swift
```

Comment: -1: That's a very fragile solution using several bad practices. Never *ever* parse the output `ls`, it fails for unusual filenames (in your case even spaces will break it). Use `find` for that. And don't trust `ls -l` columns: the date/time format for example depends on locale and is user-configurable, so it might contain fewer or more spaces. Use `readlink` to get a link's target. Also, don't use `awk` to issue system commands, use command substitution and/or `while read` loops (with `< <(...)`, `$(...)`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

here is a slightly more general solution, based on @Daniel Haley

it also preserves the symlinks for reference and asks the user to select a directory to edit.

```
ls
read -p 'Which directory do you want to update?: ' linkdir

pushd $linkdir

for linkname in $(find ./ -type l)
do
  orig=$(readlink $linkname)
  mv $linkname ${linkname}.linkbak
  cp $orig $linkname
done

popd
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for directories as well. Replace `dir` with your desired local directory:

```bash
mv ./dir ./dir.sym; cp -r $(readlink ./dir.sym) ./dir; rm -r ./dir.sym
```

This moves the symbolic directory `dir` to `dir.sym`. It then reads the source path of the just moved `dir.sym`, which still points to the same source as `dir`, and uses it to recursively copy all directory content to the new local `dir`. Finally, it removes the working copy `dir.sym`.